# Vim regex match between asterisks

Tags: vimrc

What would be the following vim regex to get the word `term` in:

```
hello my*term*here
```

My thought was:

```
*\zs[^*]\ze*
```

But it seems like there are some things I need to escape here that aren't working. The following works, but I really have no idea why -- why does the `*` not need to be escaped the first time but it does the second?

```
/*\zs[^*]\+\ze\*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to escape the `*` (with `\*`) since a `*` by itself means "zero or more repetitions of the preceding item."

When the `*` appears as the first character of the regular expression, that's an exception, since there's no preceding item, it will match a literal asterisk instead.

Note that inside a `[...]` character class, you typically don't need to escape characters with `\`, since metacharacters lose their special properties inside them.

The most correct (assuming the default setting for `'magic'`) would be:

```
/\*\zs[^*]\+\ze\*
```